# WiX: How to create a single MSI file containing Install wizard in multiple languages?

Tags: localization, wix, windows-installer

I want to distribute my app as a single MSI file.
The install wizard must show in the user's locale, for instance French or Japanese.

**QUESTION:** How to achieve this with WiX?

*Notes:*

- *[light -culture](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/do-you-speak-english) generates one MSI per culture, not what I want.*
- *The rest of my app's localization works, single MSI. Only the installer refuses to get localized.*
- *I would prefer to avoid the [use of undocumented MSI features](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/embeddedlang/index.htm) as WiX [warns against it](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Localization-issue-One-msi-file-for-several-languages-td5260178.html).*

Comment: The book WiX: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML has an entire section on creating multilingual installers. I've used that method in the past (but don't have the steps at the moment to provide an actual answer), although these days I prefer to go the route of custom bootstrappers to display installer UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn't support one .msi package having more than one language for its UI. The -cultures switch tells WiX to generate four .msi packages, one per culture.

Comment: So, just to be sure I understand: If I want a single installer, I can't use MSI, and I have to use a EXE or similar?

Comment: That's the easiest approach, yes. Starting in v4.5, MSI has support for [embedded UI handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [embedded chainers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but they're not simple.

Comment: This 4.5 tip sounds insteresting, could you develop the idea? Or do you know any open source project that uses it?

Comment: Sorry, never heard of anyone using it. There's a sample in the WiX DTF SDK: src\DTF\Samples\EmbeddedUI.